# Syncfusion grid with angular support: adding working button to rowTemplate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syncfusion

I am using a syncfusion grid and is willing to have a button in the last column.
I am using rowTemplate as described here http://help.syncfusion.com/UG/JS_CR/ejGrid.html#rowTemplate.

My grid has template as such

```
<!-- template for table rows-->
<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <tr style="background-color: {{:color}}">
    <td>{{:fullName}}</td>
    <td>{{:subjectType}}</td>
    <td>{{:statusKey}}</td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="deleteRow({{:fullName}})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

and I defined deleteRow in $scope, but it won't hit.

Table itself is simply configured to use an object as source of data and it uses angular binding.

```
   <div ej-grid="ej-grid" e-datasource="subject.list" e-allowgrouping="false" e-pagesettings-pageSize="100" e-pagesettings-currentpage="page" e-allowpaging="true" e-columns="gridColumns" e-rowtemplate="#rowTmpl" e-editsettings="gridEditSettings"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be using curly braces ({{ }})in the ng-click expression. You should write:
delete